# I have this error saying something about failed to load module scripts

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I am using webpack as the module bundler.React as the frontend and Node js as the backend.It's showing me an error in the console-`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

```
import path from "path";
export default {
  entry: "./App/Main/index.jsx",
  output: {
    filename: "App.js",
    path: path.resolve("./App/Public/src"),
  },
  mode: "production",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx|js$/,
        use: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass|.scss|.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

and the html-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="module" src="./src/App.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

I tried the way to `<script type="text/javascript" src="./src/App.js"></script>` it wasn't rendering anything but there were no errors in console.I expect that someone will help me with that.

Comment: That's because you're getting a 404 (on which note, look at your dev tools "network" tab). Check where your file actually lives, as far as your server knows, and point to that url instead.

Comment: Please, explain what the first code snippet is doing. Also, could you please specify what command you ran that printed the "Failed to load module script" error. Thanks :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "html-bundler-webpack-plugin" to compile style, script, images source files used in HTML.

Using the bundler plugin, you can specify source JS file directly in HTML.
The HTML file in the entrypoint.

Add the plugin:

```
npm install html-bundler-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- specify source JS file using relative path to the HTML file --> 
    <script type="module" src="./App/Main/index.jsx"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Add to webpack config the html-bundler-webpack-plugin:

```js
import path from 'path';
import HtmlBundlerPlugin from 'html-bundler-webpack-plugin';

export default {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./dist'),
  },
  mode: 'production',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
      entry: {
        // define templates here
        index: './App/index.html', // <= path to HTML file
      },
      js: {
        // output filename of compiled JavaScript
        filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js',
      },
      css: {
        // output filename of extracted CSS
        filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
        //inline: true, // inlines CSS into HTML
      },
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx|js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass|.scss|.css$/,
        // remove style-loader, the bundler plugin extract and can inline CSS
        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

The generated HTML file will be placed in the `dist/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- compiled JS file with hashed output filename --> 
    <script type="module" src="js/index.1234abcd.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```